# How to get data for child model with parent model serializer in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have 2 models as below:

```
# parent model
class Klass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

# child model
class KlassSettings(models.Model):
    klass = models.OneToOneField(Klass, related_name='klass_settings', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=(
    (True, 'private'),
    (False, 'public'),
))
    verify_required = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=(
    (True, 'required'),
    (False, 'not required'),
))
```

I want to create `Klass` with Django Rest Framework. I use below serializer:

```
class KlassSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='mainp-api:detail', lookup_field='pk')
    class Meta:
        model = Klass
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'title', 'description')
```

My question is: How can I get data for `KlassSettings` model (2 BooelanFields) and save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside any questions of model design here (could private and verify_required just be fields in Klass?), I believe what you are looking for is [serialzing a reverse relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations). Your final solution will look similar to what you have, but will include a `klass_settings` field in the KlassSerializer and create a KlassSettingsSerializer class.